# Mails sending failed after installation of IIS

Tags: asp.net, email, iis, vb.net-2010

**This is my C# Code**

```
try{
    var fromAddress = new MailAddress("someone@gmail.com", "someone");
    var toAddress = new MailAddress(EmailAddressTextBox.Text.Trim(), "Somename");
    const string fromPassword = "password";
    const string subject = "test1";


    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
    };
    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = "something"
    })
    {
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
}catch(Exception ex){}
```

It throws me an exception at smtp.send(message)
Exception message: Failure sending mail.
Inner Exception message: Unable to connect to the remote server
Inner Exception message:An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 74.125.25.108:587
**Note: The same code used to work fine before installation of IIS**

Comment: Try: 1) Get rid of the try/catch block, and 2) Put the `SmtpClient` into a second `using` block.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the same code used to work fine before installation of IIS. Try SuperUser.